# Which time mysql type should be use for store const "YYYYMMDD" format?

Tags: mysql

The case:

Need to store date const format that not changed in format "YYYYMMDD"?

Get const data in text file like:  20120201 20110101 etc... should put in table field

(I want to store it like date for fast queries)

I think mysql directly support it with "Date" type

The table:

```
id|   mydate   |
-------------------
1 |  20120201  |
2 |  20110101  |
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to (or should) store a date as a string?

Comment: `char(8)`,`varchar(8)`,`int(8)`, etc etc... what is the purpose of storing the data this way as opposed to the standard datetimes?

Comment: i get this from huge text file as string, but i want to store it like date for fast queries

Comment: @Yosef - so format it and store it as a date

Comment: dont need format new version of mysql support insert directly this format

Answer (score 1):

To turn into a MySQL date that can be stored in a DATE type field:

```
$original = 20120924;
$mysql_format = substr($original, 0, 4) . '-' . substr($original), 4, 2) . '-' . substr($original, 6, 2);
```

Hope that helps.

(Optionally, you could store it as an INT in timestamp format for fast results, just turn $mysql_format into a timestamp with strtotime();)

Answer (score 1):

Store it as a MySQL date type. When you need to query the info without dashes, use the MySQL replace function like:

```
REPLACE(date_column,'-','') as 'const_date'
```

to convert const_date into mysql date format upon insert/update, use MySQL CONCAT with SUBSTR like:

```
CONCAT(
      SUBSTR(const_date, 1, 4)
    , ','    
    , SUBSTR(const_date, 5, 2)
    , ','
    , SUBSTR(const_date, 7, 2)
) as 'mysql_date'
```

(Unlike PHP, MySQL does not use zero index for first char position)